# set theory: show that the following arguments are equivalent (transitivity)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i) A ⊂ B
ii) A ∩ B = A
iii) A ∪ B = B

I am stumped. I have no idea where and how to begin or what my aim is. To me, this looks like there is nothing to prove anymore, it is apparent they are equivalent.

Listing the elements doesn't seem to get me anywhere and a truth table for which elements are included in which sets also yields nothing conclusive.

A hint was given to us to show it using transitivity but simply writing that i) <=> ii) and ii) <=> iii) won't clear anything up. What notation do I have to employ to 'show' their equivalence?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the hint, or you can assume (i) holds, and then prove that (ii) holds; then assume that (ii) holds, and prove that (iii) holds; and finally assume that (iii) holds and prove that (i) holds.

In either case, you pick an implication and then you prove it. For example (i) implies (ii):

> Assume that $A\subseteq B$. We will show that $A\cap B=A$. Since $a\in A\cap B$ implies that $a\in A$ and $a\in B$ we have that $A\cap B\subseteq A$; on the other hand given an arbitrary $a\in A$, by the assumption $a\in B$. Therefore $a\in A\cap B$ and equality ensues.

Similarly, you have to write the other implications.

Answer (score 0):

$i \implies ii$

Proof by contrapositive:

Suppose $A \cap B \neq A$. Then $A \cap B$ is properly contained in $A$. This means there exists some $a \in A$ such that $a \not \in B$.  This implies that $A \subset B$ is false.

$ii \implies iii$

Substitution (in the first step), gives:
$A =A \cap B \implies A \cup B = (A \cap B) \cup B = (A\cup B) \cap (B \cup B) =A \cup B = B$

$iii \implies i$

Let $a \in A$.  Then $a \in A \cup B$. Then $a \in B$, since $A \cup B = B$.  Since $a$ is arbitrary, the claim is proven.

Now we can use the transitivity of equivalence to show that anyone of the three being true implies the other two are: $ii \implies iii \implies i$, therefore $ii \implies i, iii$.

Comment: (Edit: hitting Enter means posting..) Thank you, this is already very helpful. 

But why is A∩B inside A just because A∩B≠A? 

And what do I accomplish by finding that A∩B≠A implies that A⊂B is false? Does that automatically mean that A∩B=A implies A⊂B is true?

Comment: you're welcome; please upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We will do this step by step. First, assume (i) holds. We will prove (ii).

(i) => (ii): Define $C = B\setminus A$. Then $A \cup C = B$ and $A\cap C = \emptyset$. But then $A\cap B = A \cap (A \cup C) = (A \cap A) \cup (A \cap C) = A \cup \emptyset = A$.

(ii) => (i): We know that $A \cap B = A$.

Thus, $x \in A \Leftrightarrow x \in A\cap B\Leftrightarrow x \in A$ and $ x \in B \Rightarrow (x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B)$. These are two methods you can use to prove these kind of exercises. Now try to do (ii) <=> (iii) by yourself.